# GreenPlum vs SAP IQ Database

Tags: database, greenplum

Sorry if this question does not fit here - but would like to know about Pivotal GreenPlum Database

We are looking for alternative to SAP IQ and this open source database caught our attention - would appreciate any insights.

Any experience on migration from tradition DW products would also help.